# POST Data from MVC View by using the web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am at learning phase of web API and I want to POST data into database from the view by using WebAPI. How to hit the WebAPI from MVC.

Here is Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PatientMedicines(DomainModels.Orders.Medicines medicine, string key, string username, string FullName, string Phone, string CNIC, string address, string Email, DateTime dateofbirth, string Gender, string PaymentMethod, string PostedPrescription)
{
    SessionUser user = Session["User"] as SessionUser;
    medicine.add_with_api( key,user.Username, FullName,  Phone,  CNIC, address, Email, dateofbirth, Gender, PaymentMethod, PostedPrescription);//
    return View(new ViewModels.Orders.Medicines(user.Username));
}
```

Now Here is the Model

```
string baseUrl = ServerConfig.server_path + "/api/Payment/AddMedicineOrder";
Dictionary<string,string> parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();

parameters.Add("username",username);
parameters.Add("FullName", FullName);
parameters.Add("Phone",Phone);
parameters.Add("CNIC",CNIC);
parameters.Add("address",address);
parameters.Add("Email",Email);
parameters.Add("dateofbirth",dateofbirth.ToShortDateString());
parameters.Add("Gender",Gender);
parameters.Add("PaymentMethod",PaymentMethod);
parameters.Add("image","null");
var response =Common.ReadFromAPI<API(baseUrl,"Post",parameters);
return true;
```

How to hit this from by using POST method to insert data through api?

Comment: You should reference directly from Microsoft on how to implement this, utilize stack overflow once you understand how the creator designed this pattern. Go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You should not use your model to do it. You should create a class that will be responsible to call the API. There are a lot of examples here explaining how to do it:

[How to call API in asp.net MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129162/how-to-call-api-in-asp-net-mvc5)

[how to call web api or other restful web services in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913786/how-to-call-web-api-or-other-restful-web-services-in-c-sharp)

[Making a simple C# API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089786/making-a-simple-c-sharp-api-call)

Here a simple example calling an api from the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller  
{  
    //Hosted web API REST Service base url  
    string Baseurl = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx/";      
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()  
    {  
        List<Employee> EmpInfo = new List<Employee>();  

        using (var client = new HttpClient())  
        {  
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);  

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();  
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/Employee/GetAllEmployees");  

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)  
            {  
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  

                //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(EmpResponse);  

            }  
            //returning the employee list to view  
            return View(EmpInfo);  
        }  
     }  
}
```